# fetching gmail inbox with imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

i got a code from here to download gmail inbox:
http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

```
use these 2 hostnames 
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox
```

but getting this error.

```
 Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox in /home/medicalh/public_html/testmail.php on line 9
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out
```

i have searched on stackoverflow but did't got solution

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download my Gmail class at [my website](http://chernkuan.blogspot.com/2010/12/php-gmail-class.html): . I have also included a test file for you to test the class file.

If it does not work, I believe it could be your server's problem. You should contact your system administrator.

Comment: i have tested my code on localhost  and that works fine but not on server so i think its server problem, what should i say to my server admin? what things need to activate?

Comment: I think you can try this: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775 under the "Can you connect to the SMTP server?".. From my limited knowledge, for some of the servers, you need to ask them to activate telnet for you so that you can connect to gmail. I have read that in one of the forums some time ago. I have not encountered this problem myself

Answer (score 5):

change you host name to this one and try

```
$hostname= '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
```

and double check the username and password

Comment: Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /home/medicalh/public_html/testmail.php on line 9
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out

Comment: no luck, if i post whole code here, can you test that on your server.

Answer (score 4):

Open the `php.ini` file and remove `;` before `;extension=php_imap.dll`
and restart your server.

Your code will work...

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues with gmail IMAP SSL authentication is related to Google's account security.Once you get the login error once, sign out of all your google accounts. Then, visit this link:
  https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

[image]
Log in with the account you're attempting to access via imap.

Follow the steps and you'll then be able to login in to gmail with php imap.

It's visually shown here:
http://jeffreifman.com/filtered-open-source-imap-mail-filtering-software-for-php/configuring-gmail/

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: I was looking for days for a solution to fix this error and here it is. You're the man, thanks a lot!